# PVC not rebinding after chart reinstall

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ceph

I've got a bare-metal K8S setup.
The setup has a rook/ceph as it's storage operator and the applications claim a PVC from it. The claiming works great.
for all intents - these are the versions:

```
rook/ceph
  tag: v1.4.2
ceph/ceph
  tag: v15.2.4
```

Until...
suppose a Jenkins deployment:
this being a snippet from the Deployment.yaml for the volumes.

```
  volumes:
    - name: some-apps
      hostPath:
        path: {{ .Values.someapps_hostPath }}
    - name: "jenkins-home"
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ $fullName }}
```

This is the snippet for the pvc:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "{{ $fullName }}"
  labels:
    app: {{ $fullName }}
    chart: "{{ $chartName }}-{{ $chartVersion }}"
    release: "{{ $releaseName }}"
    heritage: "{{ $releaseService }}"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - {{ $accessMode | quote }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ $size | quote }}
{{- if $storageClass }}
{{- if (eq "-" $storageClass) }}
  storageClassName: ""
{{- else }}
  storageClassName: {{ $storageClass | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

looks completely normal.
now when i do " helm uninstall jenkins-test"
and then "helm install jenkins-test /path/to/chart/"
i dont see any of the my data that i used for the PVC.

instead i see this in the "describe pvc/pv"

```
NAME                                    STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
jenkins-test                            Bound    pvc-264373e7-6b26-4205-9b5c-aed1d3fee940   3Gi        RWX            ceph           2m36s_
[root@infra-k8s-master1 test]# kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                                           STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-264373e7-6b26-4205-9b5c-aed1d3fee940   3Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound      default/jenkins-test                            ceph                    2m43s
pvc-45ce065e-84b7-4c56-9e56-d9966dfe4634   3Gi        RWX            Retain           Released   default/jenkins-test                            ceph                    22h
pvc-5089b785-ad3c-464b-bc01-51b86af3f5df   3Gi        RWX            Retain           Released   default/jenkins-test                            ceph                    23m
```

So far, i did take an existing PVC - did `kubectl edit pv ##` and removed the claimRef field and data
then the PVC was status:Available and rebound correctly and data preserved
but this is all manual work. i was expecting something to completely automatic when i redeploy a chart with the same pvc naming and claiming.

Does each "reinstall" of the same chart deploy an entirely new set of pvc?

AFAIK - when using PVC and Provisioner like Ceph, it should re-bind the existing PVC to the redeployed chart.

Edit:
The chart is Deployment and not StatefulSet - if that matters - with 1 replica

Am I missing something in the concept? maybe I missing something? I'm puzzled here.
thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0):

You have "Reclaim Policy=Retain" for these volumes.

When the PersistentVolumeClaim is deleted, the PersistentVolume still exists and the volume is considered "released". [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain)

Comment: Im aware - i want to reuse it, thats the issue.

Comment: Then try to specify volumeName in your PVC.

Comment: i tried that: i got 
"  Warning  FailedScheduling  14s   default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: 6 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. "
i used: volumeName: {{ $fullName }}-test 
and even without the "-test"

Comment: I can see the same behaviour (FailedScheduling) with Longhorn. So unlikely it's rook/ceph specific

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see if you have any Finalizers attached as annotations to the PVC/PV which would prevent you from deleting them?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."